# Dereferencing a (template type) double pointer char causes segfault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I can't dereference a `char**`. Specifically in this context: `*(array[ currentPos ].element)`

`array` is a `vector<HashEntry>` type. My hash table holds entries of this type. The `HashEntry` type contains the following members.

`char** element` This is actually a template type, but the template I chose was `char**` so I can store pointers to strings passed in my `initTable` function rather than making copies and wasting space in my Hash Table.

`EntryType info` This is just an enum type.

In my class, I am setting the addresses of the pointer to string to `element`. So `element` contains the address of the pointer that I inserted. I need to dereference `element` to get my char* string, but this causes a segfault.

The weird thing is that when printing `element` in gdb it gives me the exact address of the pointer that points to the target string, but I cannot dereference it.

```
QuadraticHashTable<char**> table(NULL, 101); //Global Hash Table

//Main
int main()
{


    char ** docWords;

    char *s; //ifstream string buffer

    //read from ifstream and store everything that is read inside @s as a buffer
    //code that does the reading.
    //code that does the reading.
    //code that does the reading.

    docWords[0] = strtok(s, "\n");

    //Read document
    for (int i = 1; i < docSize; i++)
       docWords[i] = strtok(NULL, "\n\r");


   initTable(docWords, docSize);


   char ** wordsToFind;
   //Initialize wordsToFind to look up in hash table
   wordsToFind[0] = new char*[100];
   wordsToFind[0] = "some word";
   //repeat with the rest of the words that needs to be found

   findInTable(wordsToFind, size_of_wordsToFind);
}

//Function that init table
void initTable(char * words[], int size)
{
    //Insert words
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        table.insert(&words[i]);
    }

}

void findInTable(char * words[], int size)
{
    if (table.find(&word[0]) == NULL)
    {
        //the word has not been found
    }
}



//QuadraticHashTable.h

//Class Definition
    template <class HashedObj>
    class QuadraticHashTable
    {
      public:
        explicit QuadraticHashTable( const HashedObj & notFound, int size = 101 );
        QuadraticHashTable( const QuadraticHashTable & rhs )
          : array( rhs.array), ITEM_NOT_FOUND( rhs.ITEM_NOT_FOUND ),
            currentSize( rhs.currentSize ) { }

    //stuff
    void insert( const HashedObj & x );
    enum EntryType { ACTIVE, EMPTY, DELETED };
      private:
    struct HashEntry
    {
        HashedObj element; //created with char** type
        EntryType info;
    };
    int findPos( const HashedObj & x ) const;
    vector<HashEntry> array;

    };


//QuadraticHashTable.cpp
    template <class HashedObj>
    int QuadraticHashTable<HashedObj>::findPos( const HashedObj & x ) const
    {

//Stuff

        cout << "array[ currentPos ].element: " << *(array[ currentPos ].element) << "\n"; //SEGFAULT OCCURS HERE

//Stuff
    }

    template <class HashedObj>
    void QuadraticHashTable<HashedObj>::insert( const HashedObj & x )
    {
    // Insert x as active
    int currentPos = findPos( x );

    array[ currentPos ] = HashEntry( x, ACTIVE );

        //Stuff

    }
```

Comment: your elements are pointing to the `words` array that you pass in to `initTable`. is it being destroyed afterwards?

Comment: No they're not. `words` are dynamically allocated and initialized inside the main function.

Comment: Can you include that with your post to make complete and verifiable? you also have `table` as a local in `initTable` where `findInTable` can't access it. (and what is `currentPos`? its in `insert` and not `findPos`) Please post your *real* code

Comment: Sorry, that should have been visible to all functions. I fixed it.

Comment: The weird thing is that when printing `element` in gdb it gives me the exact address of the pointer that points to the target string, but I cannot dereference it.